# Are variables scoped to a recursive function cleared before a stack is cleared?

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration

In a node.js app I'm writing, I would like to iterate over X lines in a CSV file, transforming them into JSON objects and sending those lines (as batches of X objects) to CouchDB's `_bulk_docs` endpoint.

To do this, I'm using a generator function to expose an iterator, and then implementing the iterator via recursion (because one of the steps involves an HTTP request that executes asynchronously). If I declare variables within a recursive function, will those variables be garbage collected before the recursive iteration is complete? i.e. with the following code:

```
var vals = // call generator function;
(function doIteration() {
  var x = vals.next();
  if (!x.done) {
    doAsyncFunction(x, function(res) {
      doIteration();
    });
  };
})();
```

I think `doIteration()` function calls would complete without having to wait for the recursive stack to clear. Is that correct? Otherwise, should I move the declaration of `x` outside the function? It seems that would result in re-assigning x, which would definitely result in old referenced-values being cleaned up.

Comment: If `doAsyncFunction()` is really asynchronous, then what you've got isn't really "recursive" anyway. The asynchronous invocation of the anonymous callback will start with a fresh stack. (I'm not sure I understand whether that means the answer to your question is "yes" or "no".)

Comment: Thank you. doAsynFunction is actually `request({}, function(err, res, body) {});`. So it's defintiely asynchronous. So your comment does answer my question @Pointy. Thank you

Comment: Note that many (most) implementations will capture `x` into the lambda even though you don't use it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean @Raymond. Do you mean that the lambda function (I.e the callback?) will have access to the x variable? That is fine so long as the variable is cleaned up once the lambda execution finishes

Comment: Right. The lambda will still have access to `x` and most implementations therefore will not clean up `x` until the lambda is destroyed.